# MercurialEclipse automatically adds tag named tip

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial, repository, mercurialeclipse

I use the MercurialEclipse Plugin for Eclipse, with a - you guessed it - Mercurial repository (on bitbucket).

But unfortunately somehow my Eclipse tags all my commits with the word 'tip'
and I have no idea where and how and why.

Where can i remove it?

It's particularly annoying when I work with other people who dont tag their commits, because I always have to merge before each push.

Here are some pictures of the tag-screens,
so yuo can see that there are no tags. So it shouldn't tag anything - but it still does.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and interestingly it always says 'tip' next to my Project-Name

[image]

but why?

i dont understand - how do I remove it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the tip of your repository, it's not an actual tag created by `hg tag`.

Here's [the explanation on Mercurial's wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tip).